# FileNotFoundException after attempting to load some images with BitmapFactory.decodeStream()

Tags: java, android, bitmap, photos, picturegallery

I have the following code:

```
 InputStream stream = context.getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
 stream.close();
```

Everything works fine, but some files, with begin path "/0/file...", throws a FileNotFoundException with [object BitmapData] null.

Where am I making mistake?

**EDIT** ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Solution for me was to refresh in Photos (g+ gallery browser)

Comment: Can a path begin with /0/file... ?

Comment: yes, only this files not loaded

Comment: Solution was just refresh for my